# slf4j configuration to log a single file

Tags: java, spring, logging, logback, slf4j

logback.spring.xml is configured to log only on single class

```xml
<logger name="classname">
        <appender-ref ref="AUDIT_LOG"/>
</logger>
```

In the class there is only 1 call to log. But when i look into the log file created, there is 40 000 + lines of nonsense. There is the 1 line i wanted, but the other 40 000 lines should not be there.

How do i have to configure the logback to make sure that the log file will only contain the 1 log invcation and nothing else?

```xml
 <appender name="AUDIT_LOG" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_PATH}/audit/audit.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_PATH}/audit/audit.%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <minIndex>1</minIndex>
            <maxIndex>10</maxIndex>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <charset>utf-8</charset>
            <Pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>
        </encoder>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>INFO</level>
        </filter>
</appender>
```

Comment: Please provide whole logback.spring.xml

Comment: The `AUDIT_LOG` appender is configured to accept log events emitted by `classname` but it is also configured to accept all logs of level `INFO` so presumably the "40 000 + lines of nonsense" are INFO level events emitted by other classes in your application.

Comment: Most of the 40 000 + lines are debug, trace, error etc. the filter info actulally removed most of it. But it cant be correct, and it still gets the hilbernate i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *sounds* like you want the `AUDIT_LOG` to be reserved for one logger and **only** for that logger.

This instruction ...

```xml
<logger name="classname">
    <appender-ref ref="AUDIT_LOG"/>
</logger>
```

... directs log events from the `classname` logger to `AUDIT_LOG` but it does not prevent other log events from being handled by that appender.

If you want to ensure that the `AUDIT_LOG` appender only handles events for a specific logger then you can use a [`EvaluatorFilter`](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html#evalutatorFilter).

Here's an example using the Logback's `JaninoEventEvaluator`:

```xml
<appender name="AUDIT_LOG" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <!-- this filter will accept all log events having the logger name "classname" -->
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
        <evaluator>
            <expression>return logger.equals("classname");</expression>
        </evaluator>
        <OnMismatch>DENY</OnMismatch>
        <OnMatch>NEUTRAL</OnMatch>
    </filter>

    <file>${LOG_PATH}/audit/audit.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_PATH}/audit/audit.%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
        <minIndex>1</minIndex>
        <maxIndex>10</maxIndex>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <charset>utf-8</charset>
        <Pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Note: the evaluator expression is an ...

> arbitrary Java language block returning a boolean value as the evaluation criteria

Comment: Actually the key to solve this was to remove it froom the root tag. Although i was tol it has to be there, so i didnt suspect it at first.

Comment: @MarkoTaht that's why you have to share all the info, someone would tell you immediatelly... You should delete your question or update it, that it can be usefull for someone else in the future... Currently it is incomplete.

Comment: @Betlista i cannot give all the code since it can get me in toruble, i can only give small parts. And i dont know what are all the part one would need to get the ful picture, i have never used logback before.

Comment: nice way to ensure that the "AUDIT" appender accepts only the intended events, independently from other parts of the logback.xml.